# How to change the directory to program files using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to open a C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\Rscript.exe. For that I am trying to change the directory. I figured that the error is in opening Program files. Following is the code

```
cd Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin

Error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument Files
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike command.com/cmd.exe, PowerShell follows much more consistent rules and in the failing case `Program` and `Files\R..bin` are parsed as two *separate* arguments, where the second is invalid in context (as `cd` only accepts a *single* non-named argument).

To fix this [use quotes](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html), eg.

```
 cd "C:\Program Files"
```

With the quotes it is parsed as a string value which is supplied as  a *single* argument (the string itself does not include the quotes, again unlike cmd.exe rules).

---

FWIW, `cd` is an alias for [Set-Location](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176962.aspx). Run `get-help cd` for the details on how it can be used - include which optional (and named) parameters it *does* support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the path in quotes if it contains a space:

```psh
cd 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin'
```

Either single or double quotes will work.

Answer (score 0):

This was very helpful.

Because I was wondering why when I do Set-Location C:\Program Files, wasn't working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34358117)